# Why does logical-or cause this `-Wint-conversion` warning?

Tags: c

```
bool EnQueue(Queue *pq, Item item) {
    
    // 1. create a new node
    Node *node;
    if (QueueIsFull(pq))
        return false;
    else {
        node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (node == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    
    // 2. Copy the item to the node, update next
    node->item = item;
    node->next = NULL;

    // 3. update the rear of the queue (and front if first object)
    pq->rear->next = node;
    pq->rear  = node;
    pq->front = pq->front || NULL; // ***********************

    // 4. update the queue size
    pq->items++;
    return true;
}
```

The starred line gives me the following warning:

```
q.c:49:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    pq->front = pq->front || NULL;
```

If I remove the `||`, and just set it to one or the other value, it works fine with no warning. Why does `||` give a warning?

Comment: What's `Queue` defined as?

Comment: `a || b` evaluates to 1 or 0, and you then try to assign that int to a pointer.

Comment: What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: @dbush -- I thought it would evaluate to the first non-false object.

Comment: @dbush sort of like python, for example: `>>> False or 7` `7`

Comment: You want something like `if (!pq->front) pq->front = node;` if you want to do what the comments say you're wanting to do. (And you'll want to make sure `pq->rear` isn't null before trying to dereference it)

Comment: In C, null pointers evaluate to false in boolean context, and all non-null ones evaluate to true.  So even if the logical or operator worked similarly to Python's, your code still would not make much sense.  It would be equivalent to `pq->front = pq->front;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical OR operator `||` results in either 0 if both arguments are 0 (or NULL) or 1 otherwise.  So what that statement is doing is setting `pq->front` to the integer value 0 or 1.

You say you want the result to be the first non-null value, similar to how `or` works in Python.  If that's the case, the statement would essentially do nothing, as it would just assign `pq->front` back to itself if non-null or to NULL if it is NULL.

What you probably were looking for is:

```
if (!pq->front) pq->front = node;
```

Which would set the front of the queue to `node` if the queue is empty.

On a related note, this is a problem:

```
pq->rear->next = node;
```

if `pq->rear` is NULL.  To fix both issues, change this:

```
pq->rear->next = node;
pq->rear  = node;
pq->front = pq->front || NULL;
```

to this:

```
if (!pq->front) {
    pq->front = node;
    pq->rear = node;
} else {
    pq->rear->next = node;
    pq->rear = node;
}
```

This of course assumes that if either `pq->front` or `pq->rear` is NULL then the other is also NULL.